# Java Swagger - setting explode to false for query parameter not working properly?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to set explode to false for some of the endpoints on an API I'm working with, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. I am using the latest version of Swagger (2.2.9 as of this post). I've come up with the following contrived example, where explode is being ignored:

```
    @GET
    @Path("bogus")
    @JSONP(queryParam = "callback")
    public void bogus(
            @Parameter(description = "Extended options", in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
                    explode = Explode.FALSE,
                    style = ParameterStyle.FORM
            )
            @QueryParam("extendedOptions") String extendedOptions) {

    }
```

In general, I would like to have some specific options for the user to choose from defined in our spec, but let them know they need to include those in a comma-separated format. Code example:

```
    @GET
    @Path("bogus")
    @JSONP(queryParam = "callback")
    public void bogus(
            @Parameter(description = "Extended options", in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
                    explode = Explode.FALSE,
                    style = ParameterStyle.FORM
                    array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(type = "array", allowableValues = {"first", "second", "third"}))
            )
            @QueryParam("extendedOptions") String extendedOptions) {

    }
```

Where I'm hoping the spec will let the user know they need to format extendedOptions like this:

```
myapi.com/SomeStuffHere?extendedOptions=first,second,third
```

Not quite sure if I'm doing something wrong here, or if this option isn't completely supported in Swagger. My implementation seems to fit the documentation as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found working solution for my case. Fortunately I don't need to set mediaType to application/x-www-form-urlencoded as mentioned here [OpenApi doc](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.2.md#user-content-encodingexplode). Also there is some open bug for this: [Github bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/4065). Here is openDoc: [OpenApi doc](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/)

My working solution:

```
        @Parameter(required = false, description = "blah blah",
                explode = Explode.FALSE, array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class)))
        @RequestParam(required = false) List<String> ids,
```